# How to load only models with a specific attribute value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

```
for (var i = 1; i <= news.length; i++)   {
        var newsData = news.get(i);
        var newsRow = JST["news/row"](newsData.attributes);
        $("#news_tbody").prepend(newsRow).children('tr').addClass(function(){
            if (newsData.get('is_read') == 1)
                {return "news_read";}
            else if (newsData.get('is_read') == 0)
                {return "news_unread";}
        });
```

In this case I want to load only rows where `newsData.get('_type') == "friends"`.
I wonder how to specify it correctly.

Comment: Have a look at [filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and [where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where), which are methods that can be used on a `Backbone.Collection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_.each(news.where({ '_type': 'friends' }), function (item) {
    var newsRow = JST['news/row'](item.toJSON());
    $('#news_tbody').prepend(newsRow).children('tr').addClass(function () {
        return item.get('is_read') ? 'news_read' : 'news_unread';
    });
});
```